# SQL-Update under a external condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sql-update, date-formatting

Is it possible to limit the execution of an SQL CRUD-statement with a condition that is completely unrelated to the table it is working on?

E.g. execute the UPDATE only if there is a special date.

```
UPDATE tabfoo SET name="santa" where id="123"   // only if day = 31.12.
```

I like to have this inside a single statement. I know how to do it inside a script.
Me platform would be MySql or SqLite.

Comment: Do you mean update only if today is 31.12, or if a column value is 31.12?

Comment: `current_date` is expected to return the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQLite you can use the function `strftime()`

```
WHERE id = '123'
  AND strftime('%d.%m', CURRENT_DATE) = '31.12'
```

and for MySql the function `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
WHERE id = '123'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%d.%m') = '31.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`UPDATE tabfoo SET name="santa" where id="123" and   day = 31.12.`

otherways you may try a sql stored procedure.
[if-else doku](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL the problem can be solved next way:

```
UPDATE tabfoo 
SET name="santa" WHERE
    id="123" AND  MONTH(CURDATE()) = 12 AND DAY(CURDATE()) = 31;  // only if day = 31.12.
```

or

```
UPDATE tabfoo 
    SET name="santa" WHERE
        id="123" AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d.%m') = '31.12';
```

For SQLite you can find alternative function